# Multiple Left Join with subqueries return 'Unknown column' error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get summary statistics from a table called 'acts' which stores data about donations. In that process, I would like to get a table with statistics related to all donations, non-automatic donations (DO) and automatic donations (PA). In order to do that, I am using two left joins (on the same table but with different group by clauses).

My query returns the following error:

*Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.yr. in 'on clause'*

Could you please help me to find a solution to this problem or to suggest another way for reaching my goal? Thank you very much!

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(a.act_date)                    AS yr, 
    SUM(a.amount)                       AS sum_all, 
    COUNT(a.amount)                     AS nb_all, 
    AVG(a.amount)                       AS avg_all, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(a.contact_id))       AS unique_all,
    sum_do,
    nb_do,
    avg_do,
    unique_do,
    sum_pa,
    nb_pa,
    avg_pa,
    unique_pa
FROM
    acts a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        YEAR(act_date)                  AS yr_do, 
        SUM(amount)                     AS sum_do, 
        COUNT(amount)                   AS nb_do, 
        AVG(amount)                     AS avg_do, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(contact_id))     AS unique_do
    FROM
        acts  
    WHERE
        YEAR(act_date) >= 1991 AND
        act_type_id LIKE 'DO'
    GROUP BY
        1) 
    AS donation
ON a.yr = donation.yr_do
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        YEAR(act_date)                  AS yr_pa, 
        SUM(amount)                     AS sum_pa, 
        COUNT(amount)                   AS nb_pa, 
        AVG(amount)                     AS avg_pa, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT(contact_id))     AS unique_pa
    FROM
        acts 
    WHERE
        YEAR(act_date) >= 1991 AND
        act_type_id LIKE 'PA'
    GROUP BY
        1) 
    AS pa
ON a.yr = pa.yr_pa
WHERE
    YEAR(act_date) >= 1991
GROUP BY
    1;
```

Comment: You cannot use an alias from a SELECT in that SELECT's FROM clause.

Comment: Also, now that I look at your query a second time, you may want to do some searches here on "conditional aggregation"; this kind of query shouldn't even need a JOIN.

Comment: Thank you very much, conditional aggregation can indeed solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use alias name defined in select in the same query. For the demonstration:

```
select YEAR(a.dt) myDt, myDt from T
```

is also invalid.
Change

```
ON a.yr = donation.yr_do
```

to

```
ON YEAR(a.act_date) = donation.yr_do
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you please consider to mark it as answer so that the community can also benefit from it.